# Converting a record stored as a ParseObject to a subclass

Tags: c#, csv, subclassing

I have imported a CSV file into my Parse app. I would like to be able to access records from the table as a type subclassed from ParseObject. I can get the table, and I can get values from records using e.g. myRecord.Get("MyField"). I would prefer to get fields via properties on my subclass.

FWIW, my client is a Unity desktop app.

To illustrate what I'm after:

```
[ParseClassName( "MyRecord" )]
public class MyRecord: ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName( "MyField" )]
    public string MyField
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>( "MyField" ); }
        set { SetProperty<string>( value, "MyField" ); }
    }
    //....
}

// elsewhere...
void Example()
{
    var query = new ParseQuery<MyTable>();
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith( t =>
    {
        var anObj = t.Result.First(); // anObj is type ParseObject
        var a = anObj.Get<string>( "MyField" ); // works fine

        // somehow recast anObj to a MyRecord

        var b = myRecord.MyField;  // How do I get to this?
    } );
}
```

Is this possible?

[edit]

With regard to the idea of casting the anObj: The cast will fail because anObj is not, in fact, of type MyRecord.

My understanding of the root of the problem is that at the time I import the CVS file into Parse, Parse has no notion that the rows can map onto MyRecord, so it creates rows as plain ParseObject instances with the columns built into its dictionary. I think that Parse subclassing is, at its heart, a technique to wrap properties as accessors to the dictionary. I'm hoping (though not really expecting) that Parse provides a native way to do the binding after the fact.

Comment: Do you get an error if you cast it to a MyRecord?  eg: MyRecord rec = (MyRecord)anObj  If so can you edit your question to add the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It seems I was making this far more complicated than it actually is. (This is what comes of turning a DB naif loose on a DB. :})

I was under the misimpression that my query was returning a container holding my collection, as opposed to the collection itself. When I query for MyRecord, I get a collection that is actually of type MyRecord, which is what I was after in the first place.

Thanks for the help offered!

Answer (score 0):

I presume there is no actual object inheritance relationship here as otherwise doing a cast would work.

There are three options I can think of (If I am right about there being no inheritance).

1. Copy the properties to a type that has the extra properties using
   AutoMapper
2. Pass the base object into a constructor of a type implementing
   the additional properties
3. Build extension methods to the type you do have

1)
Essentially create like so:

```
var myRecord = AutoMapper.Map<MyRecord, ParseObject>(anObj);
// Then access properties on myRecord like you wanted, so myRecord.MyField
```

2)

```
var myRecord = new MyRecord(anObj);
// Then access properties on myRecord like you wanted, so myRecord.MyField, but you will need to copy all pertinent values yourself in the constructor
```

3)
Create a new type called MyRecordExtensions like so:

```
public static class MyRecordExtensions
{
  public static string GetMyField(this ParseObject parseObject)
  {
     return GetProperty<string>( "MyField" );
  }

  // Not sure if you need the setters at all, but just in case
  public static void SetMyField(this ParseObject parseObject, string newValue)
  {
     SetProperty<string>( newValue, "MyField" );
  }

}
```

Hope I am even close to what your issue is :)

Comment: Yes, this is close, thanks. :) I've elaborated the question a bit. Ideally, I'd be able to get Parse to bind the rows at import time, so that it creates a table of MyRecord instead of ParseObject. Next best would be Parse knows how to rebind after the fact. In practice, I'm doing something along the lines of your #2 strategy. #1 looks more elegant. I was not previously acquainted with AutoMapper, so thanks for that, too.